# Having trouble getting information from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been trying this for hours, but haven't had any luck. Every tutorial I find online gives a different method to connect to a MySQL database using PHP, so its hard to find consistency.

When I run the following code, I get "0" for the values I attempt to retrieve. How can I get the values? I have the following code so far:

```
<?php 
        //Connect to MySQL server
        $conn = mysql_connect('XXIP ADDRESSXX', 'XXUSERNAMEXX', 'XXPASSWORDXX') or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to mysql

        //Continue if connection successful
        if($conn != null) {
            $db_selected = mysql_select_db('itemdata', $conn) or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to database using the connection

            //Continue if selected database successfully
            if($db_selected == true) {
                //The statement used to query the database  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM item_prices";

                //Store the results of the query
                $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error()); //Retrieve all data from the table  

                //Convert to assoc array
                $values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

                $cost = $values['cost'];
                $retail = $values['retail'];
                $in_stock = $values['available'];

                                    echo("<p>$cost</p>");
                                    echo("<p>$retail</p>");
                                    echo("<p>$in_stock</p>");
            }
            else 
                echo "Unable to connect to database";
        }
        else
            echo "Unable to connect to MySQL Server";

        //Close database
        mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Now for some further information: With debugging, I verified that the code reaches the inner most "if" statement, so It properly connects and selects the database. None of the errors get thrown since I just receive "0" for the 3 variables I attempt to retrieve. (I tried printing right after to verify it wasn't an issue with variable scope).

Any help would be great, I've never coded a connection to MySQL and i'm having trouble finding the best method (I found tutorials on mysqli, mysql, object oriented, etc... and none are complete (I looked at the user manual also)..

Thanks.

**EDIT: The structure of the database is as follows (so far)**

database name: itemdata

table name: item_prices

The table has 4 columns:

- itemID (primary key) - this is what is searched for (type int)
- cost  (type float)
- retail (type float)
- instock (type boolean)

I'm trying to retrieve all the values in the table using itemID

**FINAL EDIT** 
I copied the table from PHPMyAdmin (this is all for test purposes, so the data is bs)

```
itemID  cost    retail  instock
0   0   0   0
1   100 150 1
2   200 250 1
3   300 350 0
4   400 450 0
5   500 550 1
10  100 150 1
11  200 250 1
12  300 350 0
13  400 450 0
14  500 550 1
```

Comment: Could you give us an idea of what your db looks like? I can see at least 3 of the columns, what type are they? Integer, etc...

Comment: I don't see any code to actually output the variables after they're assigned.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I removed that (but i'l re-add it just for test purposes in the above code)

Comment: as far as i read you use mysql_fetch_assoc expecting just one row.. you sure you got just 1 row in your item_prices table? you say you are searching an itemID but the query is generic "SELECT * FROM item_prices" where the "where" condition is? ;)

Comment: My original query was "SELECT 'cost' FROM 'item_prices' WHERE itemID = 4"

Comment: As an example for search input of 4 for the cost variaible, but I saw tutorials use the associative array this way. PS: I copied the table in my "final edit"

Comment: @Dmor574 since i cannot write code on comments, i've made an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a little look at your code and I am pretty sure (like 95%) that this is working code. If it is still not working you have done something else wrong.

By the way, you don't need to echo an error-message when you use `die()`, the script will stop working from that point.

Here's my prettified code:

```
<?php 
//Connect to MySQL server
$conn = mysql_connect('XXIP ADDRESSXX', 'XXUSERNAMEXX', 'XXPASSWORDXX')
    or die('Unable to connect to MySQL Server');


// Select db
mysql_select_db('itemdata', $conn)
    or die('Unable to connect to database');

// Run the query and fetch the results
$query = "SELECT cost FROM item_prices WHERE itemID = 4";
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));

// Echo everything
echo '<p>'.$values['cost'].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$values['retail'].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$values['available'].'</p>';

// Close the connection
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: this is much better actually, but one question. When using mysql_query() dont you need to include the $conn (connection/link) as a parameter?

Comment: Unless you have more connections running, PHP will select the correct one for you :)

Comment: This is the best answer :), but for future observers, change values['available'] to values['instock']. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. The other people answer posted snippets you could use if you want to output several values from the database (like everything).

Answer (score 1):

1) you say you are searching for an itemId but the query got no "where" condition.

2) since your table has more than one row as a result you should use mysql_fetch_assoc in this way to get all rows:

```
// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"]; 
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

if you expect just one result you can do something like this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($row);
```

and you'll get all variables yet assigned with the same names you got inside your database.

Comment: If I change my query to "SELECT * FROM item_prices WHERE itemID = X", then use the associative array, i'll have just that one record?

Comment: I got it to work this way, thank you. I misunderstood what the mysql_fetch_assoc() returned. I thought it returned an associative array of the whole table

Answer (score 1):

Since your query likely returns more than one row you need to put the fetch function in a while loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo $row["cost"];
    echo $row["retail"];
    echo $row["instock"];
}
```

Also according to your table description you have no attribute named "available".

Comment: I just realized the mistake with "available" its because I just modified it to "instock". Since this is almost identical to the previous post, i'm going to award him the answer. But thank you for the response